# Revert media query style in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I'm trying to handle media queries in JavaScript. I'm using `window.matchMedia` `query.matches` to achieve this. The thing is, I'm using multiple media queries to adjust the CSS styling from the JavaScript, and it works when sizing the window down. However, when resizing the window up, I can't figure out how to revert the styles. Here's my code so far:

```js
      //attributes.size loops over two different sizes, e.g. 600 and 1000
      let mQuery = window.matchMedia(`(max-width: ${attributes.size}px)`)

      function resize() {
        let change = {
          //change.style is changing font size, not really important here
          style: attributes.modifier.split("-")[0],
          //change.by gets the multiple font sizes (e.g. 24 and 36) we are changing too when mQuery.matches
          by: attributes.modifier.split("-")[1]
        }


        //This works
        if (mQuery.matches) {
          switch (change.style) {
            case "f":
              elms.style.fontSize = change.by + "px"
              break
          }
        } 
        //Now how do I revert the style here? How can I "grab" the original font size? Usually it's just hard coded in, see this example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_matchmedia
        else {
          switch (change.style) {
            case "f":
              elms.style.fontSize = ??
          }
        }
      }
```

Therefore my question is: how can I revert the style back, after `mQuery.matches` (see the else statement). All the examples I've seen manually revert the style, which is hardcoded into the JS, like with this example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_matchmedia. How can I avoid this and just revert the style back after the mQuery no longer matches?

Comment: `elms.style.fontSize = ""`

Comment: @Unmitigated that only works with one media query; I'm using many in a loop, so this will not work.

Comment: What do you mean? That just resets the font size to the default before it was changed with inline styles.

Comment: this may be a stupid approach, but if you want to reset it, why not just remove the CSS (literally) and just include it again? but for clarification that's basically what you want right? Also do you must use JS for this? Wouln't a simple CSS Media Query be more effective?

Comment: @Unmitigated when looping through multiple media queries, there can be the initial CSS style (48px) then an inline style of 36px then 28px. When the media query is activated and the font switches to 28px, then the screen is scaled back up again, the window will go back to 48px, completely skipping the middle queries and styles.

Comment: I agree with @Dxg125 that this seems like a job for CSS not JS.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Seems like you would be far better off using clamp with your font sizes.  Also, I don't understand the use of the switch inside an if/else???

Comment: I'm using JS since this is a sort of library. And what's wrong with putting switch inside an if/else?